# iOS: How to set the 'accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors' to true for all the ImageView of the application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, uiaccessibility

Refering to the [accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors][1], how to set the value yes for all the imageview in iOS for Swift & for Objective-C (my app get both with bridge)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can set this in the App Delegate

```swift
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   UIImageView.appearance().accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors = true
}
```